# How to remove/unset some get parameters and refresh with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, url-parameters

I want to remove some parameters of my url `www.domain.com?a=1&b=2&c=3`

For example I have this code already from stackoverflow here which works fine:

```
return location.href=location.href.replace(/&?a=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```

As I am not familiar with regex, how is it possible to add another parameter to this line?
Right now it only removes the "a" parameter. I also want the "b" parameter to be removed too.

**Edit:**
Ofcorse I am not using "a" and "b" as a parameter. How does it work with parameters like "crop-image" and "subscription" so the domain looks like: `www.domain.com?crop-image=1&subscription=1&keep=me`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `[ab]` with a set of capture groups of the parameters you want to remove.

```
location.href=location.href.replace(/&?((crop-image)|(subscription))=([^&]$|[^&]*)/gi, "");
```

Whatever is contained inside each group will match exactly against a full parameter name. You can `or` (`|`) together as many groups as you need.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you:

```
location.href=location.href.replace(/&?[ab]=([^&]$|[^&]*)/gi, "");
```

`[ab]` so that it will match one of either `a` or `b`. The `g` flag is added to make it global so that it will match multiple instances.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvAZj/)

```
var href = "www.domain.com?f=4&a=1&foo=bar&b=2&c=3";
href=href.replace(/&?[ab]=([^&]$|[^&]*)/gi, "");
console.log(href); // www.domain.com?f=4&foo=bar&c=3
```

---

Also, this part is not necessary `([^&]$|[^&]*)`, it could be simply `[^&]*` to make this regex:

```
/&?[ab]=[^&]*/gi
```

---

Due to your edit (longer attribute names), this would work for you. Note that the "or" at the end is still not required as it serves no purpose in this case.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvAZj/1/)

```
var href = "www.domain.com?ab=4&c=5&ba=2&f=10";
href=href.replace(/&?((ab)|(ba))=[^&]*/gi, "");
console.log(href); //www.domain.com?&c=5&f=10
```

Notice that this will leave an `&` at the beginning if the first attribute is removed? This shouldn't cause any issues but if you would still like to fix that, you could do this:

```
href=href.replace(/&?((ab)|(ba))=[^&]*/gi, "").replace(/\?&/,"?");
```

With this you will end up with `www.domain.com?c=5&f=10` instead of `www.domain.com?&c=5&f=10`. While it is possible to do it within a single regex, especially in javascript without lookbehinds it's much easier and more compact (less repetitive) to do it in a separate regex like I did above.

Comment: im using not "a" and "b" as parameters. im using some strings like "crop-image" and "subscription". I end up in an error if i replace "[ab]" with "[crop-imagesubscription]". sorry but I dont get this regex thing ^^

Comment: @ggzone, if you would have mentioned that ahead of time I would have gave a different solution from the beginning. I've updated my answer, note that you still don't need the condition for the end. I also accounted for cases where you will end up with `com?&c=...`

Comment: yeah thanks. i see you had the most ambition to answer my question. but it was not perfect, even if i started to edit my question a bit too late. nevermind you helped me alot and i guess you deserve an approved answer aswell. but Syon was a bit faster... just sorry ^^

Comment: @ggzone Did you atleast reduce the `([^&]$|[^&]*)` to `[^&]*`? The `[^&]$` part would only ever catch if there is only a single non-& character after the `=` before the end of the string... which `[^&]*` would also catch.